# req.session.passport is empty, deserializeUser not called - ExpressJS, Passport

Tags: node.js, session, express, passport.js

I am having problems using sessions in Passport/ExpressJS.

When I log `req.session`, I can see that passport is `{}`:

```
{ cookie: 
 { path: '/',
  _expires: Mon Sep 29 2014 19:37:16 GMT-0300 (BRT),
  originalMaxAge: 3594522,
  httpOnly: true,
  secure: true },
passport: {} }
```

Also, I am authenticating with Facebook, and `passport.deserializeUser` is not being called.
This is my code:

```
    passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({

    // pull in our app id and secret from our auth.js file
    clientID        : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret    : configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL     : configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL

},

// facebook will send back the token and profile
function(token, refreshToken, profile, done) {

    // asynchronous
    process.nextTick(function() {

        console.log("profile " + profile.id);
        console.log("profile.name "+profile.name.givenName)

        // find the user in the database based on their facebook id
        User.findOne({ 'facebook.id' : profile.id }, function(err, user) {

            // if there is an error, stop everything and return that
            // ie an error connecting to the database
            if (err)
                return done(err);

            // if the user is found, then log them in
            if (user) {
                //returning undefined
                //console.log(user.name + " " + user.email);
                return done(null, user); // user found, return that user
            } else {
                // if there is no user found with that facebook id, create them
                var newUser = new User();

                // set all of the facebook information in our user model
                newUser.facebook.id    = profile.id; // set the users facebook id
                newUser.facebook.token = token; // we will save the token that facebook provides to the user
                newUser.facebook.name  = profile.name.givenName + ' ' + profile.name.familyName; // look at the passport user profile to see how names are returned
                newUser.facebook.email = profile.emails[0].value; // facebook can return multiple emails so we'll take the first

                // save our user to the database
                newUser.save(function(err) {
                    if (err)
                        throw err;

                    // if successful, return the new user
                    return done(null, newUser);
                });
            }

        });
    });

}));

// used to serialize the user for the session
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log("serialize");
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    console.log("deserialize");
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
        console.log(user);
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

I've tried moving both methods to the beginning but it didn't make any difference. `passport.serializeUser` is called just fine.

This is where I initiliaze `passport`:

```
app.use (cookieParser());
app.use(session({ secret: 'appsecret', saveUninitialized: true, cookie: { secure: true, maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000) }, key:'connect.sid' }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

And this is my `route`:

```
// =====================================
// FACEBOOK ROUTES =====================
// =====================================
// route for facebook authentication and login

app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : 'email' }));

// handle the callback after facebook has authenticated the user
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect : '/home',
        failureRedirect : '/login'
    }));
```

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you show us the code where Passport is initialized ? People often forget to initialize it, or do it in a wrong order.

It should be initiliazed like this : `app.use(express.session({ secret: 'keyboard cat' }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());`

Also, could you show us the code for the authentication route ?

Comment: Edited in the question :)

Comment: Ok, everything seems alright to me. Dumb question : you said that `passport` is empty when you log out `req.session`. Where (in the code) did you do it ?

Also, you said *`passport.serializeUser` is called just fine.*, but what happens when you try to log the `user` param ?

Comment: I log it out in app.get('/home'), which is the route called when the authentication is successful. user is undefined

Comment: Okay, so the authentication itself is probably never successful...
Another dumb question : since you're logging out in `app.get('/home')`, I am assuming you're visiting `/home` only *after* signing in (otherwise, it's normal `req.session.passport` is undefined).
Could you now log out `user` and `err` at the beginning of `User.findOne`'s callback ? 
We'll get to the bottom of this :)

Comment: user is correct (it is filled in with facebook data like email and name). err is null

Comment: That's very weird. `user` should be defined in `serializeUser`. The example suggests the following code `app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
function(req, res) {
res.redirect('/home');
});` for the authentication route. It shouldn't make any difference but could you try that ?

Comment: yeah, I agree, but serializeUser is only called afterwards. It didn't work with this route (didn't even call passport authentication).

Comment: @WaldoJeffers anything else that I should try/check?

Comment: @Daniel I would like to know this as well, I have the same issue.

Comment: No, I still haven't solved this issue :(

Answer (score 8):

### Background

For me the issue with deserializeUser not being called and empty passport object was cross-domain issue. When I was sending ajax request from localhost:4200 to localhost:1000 cookies and sessions didn't work for my Ember.js client. However, Postman extension received correct response. Also passport object was filled with data correctly. User.deserializeUser was getting called correctly.

### Solution

To solve this I had to set correct server-side and client HTTP headers.
Server-side(node.js + express + passport):

```
# The important part. Must go AFTER the express session is initialized
app.use passport.initialize()
app.use passport.session()

# Enable CORS
# X-Requested-With, X-AUTHENTICATION, X-IP
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/18290875/2166409
app.use (req, res, next) ->
  res.header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200'
  res.header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, X-AUTHENTICATION, X-IP, Content-Type, Accept'
  res.header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true
  res.header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
  next()

app.use '/api/v1', router
```

Client-side:

If using jQuery add this to $.ajax options:

```
xhrFields: { withCredentials:true }
```

Then everything works as expected:

```
DESERIALIZE USER
{ id: '547fabf22a098ade53e6e48e',
  name: 'test',
  firstName: 'test',
  email: 'test@wp.pl' }
LOGIN SUCCESS SESSION
{ cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: Thu Dec 04 2014 20:26:52 GMT+0100 (CET),
     originalMaxAge: 3597205,
     httpOnly: false },
  passport: 
   { user: 
      { id: '547fabf22a098ade53e6e48e',
        name: 'test',
        firstName: 'test',
        email: 'test@wp.pl' } } }
```

These answers helped me: [about Ember.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18290875/2166409), [jQuery.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23660618/2166409).

Comment: You can see if there is cors issue, by peeping into js console and then overcome it in development by using --disable-web-security flag on your browser.

Answer (score 6):

For me, the root cause was the cookie security value in the express-session.

```
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'crackalackin',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie : { secure : false, maxAge : (4 * 60 * 60 * 1000) }, // 4 hours
}));
```

On my local machine, I wasn't running over HTTPs so when cookie.secure is true, the session and user object were empty. When in dev mode and secure was false, it worked correctly.

Comment: This solved it for me after hours of searching! Thanks!

Comment: It took me only 1 hour of searching but still this solved it for me, thanks!

Comment: You are my lifesaver! Thanks, Greg, I tried disabling cors and it didn't work but your solution worked lovely.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to be consistent in linking the different pages of my site.

Prefixing the URL of a link with 'www.' while authenticating where there is no 'www.' will start a new session when linking to that prefixed page.
You can check this with a cookie viewer, see if there's multiple cookies for each of the two options.